# Calendar methods doesn't work on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to use some methods that should work in a Calendar, for example :

```
public void calculaSemanal(){
          CoffeeCalendar coffeeCalendar = CoffeeCalendar.getInstance();
        int week = coffeeCalendar.get(CoffeeCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
                }
```

but "create method getInstance()"appears;
obs: i have java.util.Calendar imported, JDK version 1.8

Comment: Is the method public? Show relevant code oft `CoffeeCalendar`

Comment: What is `CoffeeCalendar` and how is it related to `java.util.Calendar`?

Comment: `CoffeeCalendar` is not part of the standard JDK library

Comment: yes it's public, 
private com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar coffeeCalendar;
I've already tried to put the calendar public
and CoffeeCalendar it's a class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're after with CoffeeCalendar, but the java.util.Calendar package does what your code is trying to do:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int week = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```